# Fast way of comparing nested lists of strings

Tags: python, optimization, comparison

I am trying to compare two nested lists of strings with each other and searching for the **fastest way possible**. To do that I am currently calculating the Jaccard-index (intersection / union) between each of the elements of the nested lists.
Example:

```
list1=[["abc","def","ghi"],["jkl","mno"]]
list2=[["pqr","def","stu"],["jkl","mno","vwx"]]
```

In this example, the first "cluster" of the first list is compared with each of the cluster of the second list, which results in 4 (2*2) different jaccard indeces.

However, my problem is, that my two lists each contain about 500.000 clusters/elements (sublists) each. With my current code, it will take me about 2 weeks to compute. At this point I am not able decrease the computing time and asking for help.

Current code:

```
for i1 in list1:
    for i2 in list2:
        intersection = set(i1) & set(i2)
        union = set(i1) | set(i2)
        jaccard = (len(intersection) / len(union)) * 100
        if jaccard > 1:
             #write to file....
```

Comment: What's your desired output for your example inputs?

Comment: Are the two lists approximately the same size? is it 500K clusters or 500K elements in total (i.e. sum of lengths of sublists)?

Also, are the elements in the lists sorted?

Comment: jaccard (IoU) value can't be above 1; 1 is the maximum value, achieved when the two lists are identical.

Comment: @jpp The desired output is the jaccard-index, when it is higher than 1, I am writing it into a new file

Comment: @Mircea to be precise, the size of the lists are 544.866 and 593.345. The lists are unordered. Also, the jaccard-output will be in percentage, as I multiplied with 100.

Comment: Am I correct to think you just want to check if `any` element overlaps?

Comment: @zipa I want to check whether two elements overlap and if they do, to what degree they overlap

Comment: try a pool.map (http://chriskiehl.com/article/parallelism-in-one-line/)

Comment: If len(intersection) = 1 and len(union) = 99 you are writing to file. Unless your clusters can have over 100 difference in size, you are only checking if any element overlaps, as you will always write to file unless no element overlaps. Need more data about your real lists, maybe you can upload them somewhere?  Does not need to be all, but at least 5000 elements of each list if they are representative enough

Answer (score 0):

this won't give you a **huge** boost in performance but
if your inner lists are short (2 or 3 elements like in your example) one thing you could do is intersect\union the lists yourself, its usually faster to do it like this: `[val for val in i1 if val in i2]` instead of like this `set(i1) & set(i2)` 
for intersection and for union use this: `[val for val in i1 if val not in i2] + i2`.

i tried comparing both methods where both lists contain about 500k sublists and each sublist constains 3 random strings and it reduced the time it takes for a single iteration (of the outer loop) from about 0.6 seconds on average to about 0.45 seconds on average (averaging the first 100 cycles) at least on my machine.

the reason stuff like this can affect performance by 25% is because python has a lot of overhead in data manipulation that fortunately can sometimes be minized but i think the lesson from this (unfortunately) is to not use python for large data sets because it is very inefficient when it comes to stuff like this